# SQL Statement keeps returning all rows instead of a few

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have asp.net site which contains 13 textboxes where a user can enter in certain information to search through a database. A gridview populates the data. The data is only for viewing purposes.

My issue is, every row is always returned. If a user types data into only one field, then only the rows containing that data should be returned. Instead, every row is returned no matter what and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my SQL Statement.

Here is the entire code:

```
 SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strings.settings.connectionString);
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT SOPID, CONTACT, SHIPTONAME, KNOWN_EMAIL, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE, PHONE1, CUSTPO, CID, AID, SEATS FROM dbo.LOOKUP_TEST_TBL WHERE CONTACT = @CONTACT OR SHIPTONAME = @SHIPTONAME OR KNOWN_EMAIL = @KNOWN_EMAIL OR ADDR1 = @ADDR1 OR ADDR2 = @ADDR2 OR CITY = @CITY OR STATE = @STATE OR ZIPCODE = @ZIPCODE OR PHONE1 = @PHONE1 OR CUSTPO = @CUSTPO OR CID = @CID OR AID = @AID OR SEATS = @SEATS", mySqlConnection);
    //AccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDERID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtOrderID.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTACT", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtContact.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SHIPTONAME", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtShipToName.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KNOWN_EMAIL", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtEmail.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtAddress1.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR2", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtAddress2.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITY", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtCity.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtState.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIPCODE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtZip.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONE1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtPhone.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTPO", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtCustomerPO.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtCustomerID.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtAddressID.Text.ToUpper();
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEATS", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtSeats.Text.ToUpper();
    mySqlConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows == false)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Any tips or advice or a point in the right direction would be fantastic! Thanks everyone!

Comment: As a suggestion, you should be using a `using` block with classes that implement the IDisposable interface, especially with sqlConnection, since if an exception is generated, your code won't close the connection.

Comment: Perhaps you should try re-writing the SQL Statement Know the difference between using `AND` vs `OR` if one passes and the rest of the results will be returned as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query shoul look like

```
SELECT *  
FROM dbo.LOOKUP_TEST_TBL 
WHERE (CONTACT = @CONTACT and CONTACT is not null) or
      (SHIPTONAME = @SHIPTONAME and SHIPTONAME  is not null).....
```

just exclude the nullable records

Comment: Nice, this is a lot cleaner than mine :S

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly the query -- it will return any rows that have empty columns in any of those fields, which the user didn't provide.

I would try constructing the query using only the columns that the user has specified.

Get the non-empty parameters:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    { "@CONTACT", txtContact.Text.ToUpper() },
    { "@ADDR1", txtAddress1.Text.ToUpper() },
    // etc
};
var enteredParams = values.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value));
```

And construct the query:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT ... WHERE {0}",
    string.Join(" OR ", 
        enteredParams.Select(kvp => 
            kvp.Key.TrimStart(new char[] { '@' }) + " = " + kvp.Key
        )
    );
```

And finally construct the parameters:

```
foreach (var kvp in enteredParams)
{
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

(Unchecked for exact syntax, but I think you get the idea.)

Comment: Even if I were to change OR into AND, it would still return rows with empty columns correct?

Comment: wow, thank you for this. I get the idea, let me try a couple things and i shall return

Comment: I will admit, I am struggling a little with the query syntax, this is brand new ground for me

Answer (score 0):

You OR everything in your WHERE clause together, so if even ONE of the things matches it'll be included in the results. Did you maybe mean to AND them together instead?